# How does Dirac prove that the canonical coordinates $q_r$ form a complete commuting set of observables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, commutator

I'm reading "The principles of quantum mechanics" by Paul Dirac, and I've reached the point where he introduces the momentum operator.

After showing that the $p_r$'s commute with each other and with the $q_r$'s just like the operator $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dq_r}$ does, he writes that there is no inconsistency stating that $$p_r=-i\hbar\frac{d}{dq_r}$$
After that he writes:

> This possibility enables us to see that the q's must form a complete commuting set of observables, since it means that any function of the q's and p's could be taken to be a function of the q's and $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dq}$'s and then could not commute with all the q's unless it is a function of the q's only.

I seem to understand that he's saying that a hypotetical function $f=f(q_r, p_r)$ could be written as well as $f=f(q_r, -i\hbar\frac{d}{dq})$, which makes sense. However, after that he says that such $f$ "could not commute with all the q's unless it is a function of the q's only". But why would this function commute with the q's if it is a function of $-i\hbar\frac{d}{dq}$ as well? How do we conclude that the q's form a complete commuting set of observables?